# Solve the Recurrences

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

To prove $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ :
$$
T(n)\le\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
c_1 & n\le 1 \\
\max_{1\le i \le n}(T(i) + T(n-1-i)) + c_2n & n>1
\end{array}\right.
$$

I think it is necessary to simultaneously prove  $T(n) = O(n^2)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ .

But I don't have any clue about proving $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$, could you help me? Or there may be any other methods?

Comment: The definition of $\Omega(g(n))$ of some function $g(n)$ is the set of all functions $f(n)$ such that $0 \leq cg(n) \leq f(n)$ for some positive constants $c, n_0$ with $n \geq n_0$. To show that $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ we assume $T(n) \geq cn^2$ and substitute into the recurrence for $T(n)$ you provided to verify that $T(n) \geq cn^2 = \Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: I'm not sure the bound $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ is accurate. The recurrence relation is very similar to the recurrence relation modelling the cost of the optimal matrix chain product problem, whose bound is $T(n) = \Omega(n^3)$.